# Solve conditional equation with two variables, and one variable within a range

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a simple equation s=n/r, knowing that s and n are between 0 and 1, and r>0, how do I find the values of n and s that make this equation true?
I am interested in proceeding in two ways. 
(i) Set a value for r and then find all n,s pairs that solve the equation
(ii) Find all values of r,s,n when the equation is true, always by keeping the constraints mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triplet $(r,n,s)$ is a solution of the equation with the other conditions iff
$$(r,n,s)\in (0,\infty)\times (0,\min(1,r))\times \{n/r\}$$

Comment: thank you but what does that mean? I don't understand how to practically implement this notation. Why did you write that the triplet can go from 0 to infinity?

Comment: If you have a triplet, you can check if it is in the set I've given. It is in the set iff it fulfills the conditions and the equation, e.g. $(1,0.5,0.5)\in (0,\infty)\times (0,1)\times \{0.5\}$ so it is a suitable solution

Comment: I do not have values for a all three variables. I just want to find all possible solution when n or r are known.

Comment: When $r$ is known, you can take any $n\in (0,\min(1,r))$ and then you must take $s=n/r$, so you get all possible solutions, that's what I've written in my solution.